# Accuracy of repeated measuring of binary data

Tags: probability, binary-data, accuracy

Suppose there is a device that can measure binary data (0 and 1) with 90 percent accuracy. I have used this device and measure the same data twice (or in another scenario three times). If in both measurements the device shows `0`, what will be the accuracy of two (or three times) measurement in total (i.e. what is the probability that data is actually `0`)?

Hear is a possible solution but I am not sure if it is correct (or if it has a name).

If measuring twice: $$A = 0.9 + (0.9*(1-0.9)) = 0.99$$
If measuring three times: $$B = A + (.9*(1-A)) = 0.999$$

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your solution is incorrect.

One way you could get 90% accuracy would be if your underlying process yields 1 with a probability of 0.1 and 0 with a probability of 0.9, iid... and your device outputs 0 *in all cases*. You now have a (completely useless) device with 90% accuracy.

If you measure an observation multiple times, you will always get a 0, because that is your device's constant output.

But that doesn't change the fact that the probability it *actually* is 0 is still 0.9. No matter how often you measure.

---

This is related to the fact that [accuracy is not the best measure for assessing classification results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352).